# Error while installing Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, uefi

when i insert the burned disc with `.ISO` image and run the auto-play. It gives Error :

```
wibu does not currently support EFI
```

what to do?

Comment: Do you mean Wubi? That's deprecated and doesn't really work on EFI platforms indeed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](/q/6328) or [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](/q/221835)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your install process correctly, you're doing it wrong.  You must boot from the DVD as if it were a live DVD.  You can't just run the auto-play.

If you are booting it live and you're getting this message, then for some reason your disk is trying to boot EFI and your machine can't do EFI, or your machine is trying to boot EFI and the disk can't.  The solution is to disable secure boot and enable legacy boot inside your UEFI BIOS configuration.